# How to Display a String in PDF format using Android

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I am Developing an Android Application in which my current task is to open the given Text 
in PDF format . I am unable to do this

```
   eg -Given text is "This text should be displayed as a pdf document ".
```

I googled a lot but no idea about how to do it . Google docs is providing the facility to open pdf files from given url but i dont have the pdf files on a url , I just have a string text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by using iText Library of Java I have implemented similar kind of solution

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPDF/article.html

follow the link and just change the requirement as per android

Comment: Dear friend in android we avoid to create files on mobile so i was looking for an alternate

Comment: Then how could you expect a string to behave like pdf. I think your task must be to extract some text from somewhere then show that in PDF format and this is the method(Itext library) which does the same